# Can't get rid of "Splitview controller is expected to have a view controller at index 0 before it's used" error in iOS6

Tags: ios, ios6, uisplitviewcontroller, ipad

I'm trying to convert my app to universal for iPad support and whatever I do I can't get rid of the "Splitview controller  is expected to have a view controller at index 0 before it's used!" error right after the app stars.

I'm using iOS6 as target, XCode 4.6.3. Tried all the things that I could find on this website and Google, didn't help me at all.

I want to add a TabBar controller as a Main one (left one in the Split Controller) and some other controllers as a detail one.
Here is my current code in AppDelegate.m:

```
tabController = [[UITabBarController alloc] init];
[tabController setViewControllers:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:navAddVC, nav, svcNav, stvcNav, nil]]; 
FirstDetailViewController *fdvc = [[FirstDetailViewController alloc];
initWithNibName:@"FirstDetailViewController" bundle:nil];
UINavigationController *fdvcNav = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:fdvc];
viewControllers = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:tabController, fdvcNav, nil];
UISplitViewController *splitvc = [[UISplitViewController alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];
[[splitvc view] setBackgroundColor:[UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"splitViewControllerBG"]]];
[splitvc setViewControllers:viewControllers];
[splitvc setDelegate:fdvc];
[[self window] setRootViewController:splitvc];
[[self window] makeKeyAndVisible];
```

I'd appreciate any help, thanks.

Comment: Did you try setting `viewControllers` before loading the view to set the background color?

Comment: @Wain Thank you! That was it. Stupid me, didn't pay attention to this detail.

Comment: @Wain Thanks, this warning wasn't displayed before. Don't why it appears suddenly

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Thanks to @Wain I solved it.

The thing was that by setting up a background image to my split vc I was loading its view.
So the solution is to set viewControllers array before the setting background color.

Comment: This also applies to setting other properties of the UISplitViewController such as `setPreferredDisplayMode`. Just configure them after setting the VCs.